# Polymer two drawer inside component

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I am using the example code for two drawers found here.

```
<app-drawer-layout>

  <app-drawer swipe-open></app-drawer>

  <app-drawer id="endDrawer" align="end" swipe-open></app-drawer>

  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title></div>
    <paper-icon-button icon="info" onclick="document.getElementById('endDrawer').toggle();"></paper-icon-button>
  </app-toolbar>

  <sample-content size="100"></sample-content>

</app-drawer-layout>
```

This works if I put the code on in index.html but If I put it inside a component, and then reference the component in index.html, I get the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toggle' of null

Can anyone please shed some light on this?

Note: This error happens in Chrome but not Safari. Haven't tested anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because inside a component code the `document.getElementById` will not work as expected. Do you have Shadow DOM enabled by any chance?

You should use [Polymer's event binding syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/events#annotated-listeners) and get the element using the [node finding feature](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding).

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
  </template>
    <paper-icon-button icon="info" on-tap="toggleEndDrawer"></paper-icon-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
  Polymer({
    is: 'my-app',

    toggleEndDrawer: function() {
      this.$.endDrawer.toggle();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I could only get it to work with on-tap="toggleEndDrawer" though but everything else worked!

Comment: Oh, of course, my mistake. `onclick` is the built-in handler.